# Wireless drivers on install?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, drivers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I've been having this question since ubuntu 9.xx, hopefully you guys know what I can do. Is it possible to  make it detect the wireless drivers on installation (11.10) ? I currently have a desktop with a wireless adapter and it's annoying having to unplug it, get it 2 floors below where the actual modem is, connect it directly and install everything. There should be a more efficient way to do this right? I don't know why ubuntu doesn't do this by default it'd be a nice feature specially for laptops I think.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My wireless card is Broadcom Corporation BCM4318 [AirForce One] 802.11g Wireless LAN Controller (rev 02)

Comment: What is the model of the adapter? Can you add that info to the original question.

Comment: The installation media has some wireless drivers, like broadcom for my device, and if you tick the option 'install 3rd party software' during install it will enable the driver before the partitioner screen comes up.  Works for me

Comment: I updated the question with my card info, @duffydack I tried doing that but it didn't do enything in the end it stills says (firmware missing) on the wireless network :(

Comment: what is the output exactly of `lspci | grep Network`  we need the model number of your card

Comment: Just added the output of `lspci | grep Network`, I guess there must be a way to install these drivers offline

Comment: according to the ubuntu wiki for broadcom chipsets, you need the b43 driver which means I guess you need the firmware-b43-installer (which will also install b43-fwcutter), but is not on the install media.  I have a model supported by the STA driver, and is on the install disc, so Im lucky.

Comment: Meh I ended up plugin my comp directly to the modem, kind of a hassle but way faster :)

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, then please flag explaining that (as well as editing your question with any details you have).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a Broadcom wireless card, and the drivers for Broadcom are not included on the installation media, the answer is no. You have to install the OS first, reboot, then install the driver. Sorry.

If out of the box functionality is important, consider, if possible, switching to an Intel wireless card.

Comment: Well it's not that big of a deal, more like a convenience issue I wish I could install the wireless drivers without actually connecting my comp directly to the modem.